# Find DWORD Size

Tags: visual-c++

I am new in vc++... I have one doubt in vc++. what is the size of GetTickCount() function.The return type of  GetTickCount() is DWORD. Please anyone Answer for my question.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of a function means the number of bytes occupied by the code that belongs to the function. You can find this out using a debugger like Windbg. But this is not useful information in most cases. To get the size of a data type, you can use the `sizeof` operator. Since the return type of `GetTickCount` is `DWORD` (4 bytes), you can either do `sizeof(DWORD)` or `sizeof(GetTickCount())` to get its size. There is also a function by the name `GetTickCount64` which returns `ULONGLONG` which is a 64-bit unsigned value (8 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

`GetTickCount()` returns a `DWORD` which is 4 bytes. The function itself can be represented using its start address (function pointer) which will have size equal to size of `void*` which is 4 bytes on 32-bit systems and 8 bytes on 64-bit systems. Finding the size of code that the function occupies can be problematic and is rarely needed.